# Firebase tracking/limiting of user request volume

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am creating a SaaS Firebase application in which users create and own "documents" which may be accessed frequently (in the range of tens or hundreds of thousands of times per month) by anonymous users via the REST API.

I'd like to pass along the cost of access to users by allocating them a quota in either number of requests per month or volume of data transfer per month to the documents they own. They could subscribe to a paid plan to increase this quota.

Is it possible to track/cap user access in this way with Firebase?

Comment: Nothing is built in for this. But you can probably track the operations that you want to allow a quota on and then disallow reads/writes when the usage exceeds the quota. Main problem is tracking the actual usage, which will need some elaborate security rules to prevent the potential for abuse. Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if firebase has an api for that (Didn't see anything as I looked through) - any firebase reps with answers on stack overflow?

This seems to suggest there is nothing in place which would let you run securely without proxying requests through a server.
https://www.quora.com/Is-Firebase-a-secure-service-Why-or-why-not