# Firebase usage analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Is it possible to get usages information according to some criteria , per app basis or even per user basis in a project? 
I'am wondering if there is any way to make people pay for exactly what they are using : uploads, downloads, reads writes and deletes bandwidth and so on !

Comment: There is no built-in functionality to break down usage of Firebase products per user of your apps. If you need this for your app, you will have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**[FirebaseAnalytics.Event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event)**

An Event is an important occurrence in your app that you want to measure. You can report up to 500 different types of Events per app and you can associate up to 25 unique parameters with each Event type.

`ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE`

E-Commerce Purchase event. This event signifies that an item was purchased by a user.
Params:

```
CURRENCY (String) (optional)
VALUE (double) (optional)
TRANSACTION_ID (String) (optional)
TAX (double) (optional)
SHIPPING (double) (optional)
COUPON (String) (optional)
LOCATION (String) (optional)
NUMBER_OF_NIGHTS (long) (optional) for hotel bookings...
```

For Enhanced Analytics take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality to break down usage of Firebase products per user of your apps. If you need this for your app, you will have to build it yourself.

Related questions:

- [Firebase tracking/limiting of user request volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513198/firebase-tracking-limiting-of-user-request-volume)